# Code lens is enabled but referenced are in blank visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, codelens

Hello there I have enabled CodeLens in visual studio 2013, but referenced are not shown on the methods. they are just showing '-References'

Comment: Does the project build without issues? Is it language specific? Does the solution contain a single or multiple languages? Is there anything in the output window? What version of Visual Studio do you have installed (update4? update 5 RC?), are you connected to a TFS server, if so, what version is that?

Comment: @jessehouwing I have version VS2013 with update 4

Comment: Do you have any plugins that can conflict with it? Can you save your Visual studio settings and try resetting them? It seems like an ide issue. Has this happened before update 4? What triggered this?

Comment: i just solved the same problem for me.

Comment: @hdkhardik i pressed mistakenly, "Enter", and my answer after the "me." didn't reach you.. sorry. my bad. 
I had the same solving with you. Sorry again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After researching since past 1 and half week I found that , there was another source control installed and selected, I have installed VisualSVN and itwas selected as a source control in Visual Studio IDE.
I could resolve this issue by following the given steps.

Goto **Tools-> Options -> Source Control -> Plug-in Selection** and selected **None** in **Current source code Plug-in**
Thank you all !!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a circular reference in one of the projects in my solution.

My solution had three projects. One was called 'SendGrid' and it used the Sendgrid api and such, but my project assembly name was also called 'SendGrid' and I must have accidently referenced its own dll. Took that out and all three projects started working with code lens again.

Answer (score -1):

Enabled the CodeLens in below mentioned steps.

Goto Tools->Options->Text Editor->All Languages->CodeLens -> Enable CodeLens (Checked).